# C Get pid of process launched with execl

Tags: c, pid, execl

I'm launching a process with the instruction

```
execl("./softCopia","softCopia",NULL);
```

softCopia is just a dummy that writes integers in a file.

I would like to know how can i get the pid of this process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all of the Unix exec functions **replace** the running process with the new one, the PID of the exec'd process is the same PID it was before.

So you get the PID by using the `getpid()` call, *before* calling `execl`.

Or, if you actually want to continue running your main program and launch a new program, you use `fork()` first. The `fork()` function returns a negative value for errors, 0 for the new, child process, and the PID of the child in the parent. So the parent can then use one of the `wait` functions or just continue on its business until later.